# Trouble with pg_connect in connecting to Heroku

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I created a PHP app on Heroku and I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database I set up on Heroku.

I put a snippet like this into the project:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=thehost.amazon.whatever port=1010 dbname=blahblah user=jooghaha password=foofoo sslmode=require options='--client_encoding=UTF8'") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
```

However, when I try to request the file in the app, the server returns a generic HTTP 500 Error, and the Heroku logfiles say

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /app/www/pages/database.php on line 23
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The one line you posted looks fine. Assuming that line is really line 23 of /app/www/pages/database.php, you should look at the surrounding few lines to find the parse error. Often, PHP is not so precise at telling you where a syntax error is. Look in particular for unbalanced parentheses, missing semicolons, etc. in the lines above that snippet.